# Iframe with "bookmarks" without the main browser jumping?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink, bookmarks

I have several iframes on my main page each of which are src="".  I have jquery set up such that when a I click a button the src for the related iframe fills up to say website.com/#title1.

However, the problem I'm having is that when the iframe's browser window jumps to the appropriate line, the main browser jumps to the iframe.  How can I have the iframe do its job with the "bookmark" while the main browser ignores the jump?

I've read the first 2 answers, but I'm kind of not sure how to implement it.

my jquery code:

```
$("button.help_popup_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("iframe", "div#help_popup_" + this.value).attr({
            src : 'https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#filters',
        });
});
```

I tried that but the main browser still jumped

Answer (score 0):

```
return false
/* - or - */
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this... checked added info... thanks!